# Powershell - Cannot run multiple commands in PS ISE

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I was writing command to get member group of a computer and was then performing a remove operation and then again displaying the membership of computer but the third line of code to display new membership never runs. Also, removal operation runs while displaying membership data from 1st line of command. I can understand that there might be delay, I tried Start-sleep as well but again in same format.

I am pasting output here, removal command is removed and just showing two commands that displays membership, I also included a text, which surprisingly comes first but should be displayed after displaying group membership

Please let me know of your thoughts.

[image]

Comment: you have run into the "delay the output stream to see if anything of the same type shows up so they can all be grouped into one" glitch. [*grin*] the FIRST object in the display determines the properties that will be shown. your two commands have different props, so the 2nd is not shown. note that he lines ARE shown as blanks, tho. ///// the fix = add '| Out-Host` to the end of the two commands to force them to the screen _right freaking now_ ...

Comment: Thnx Lee, that helped and I hope MS is working on a fix for this, if someone from their team is looking here or they are already aware of this !!

Comment: you are most welcome! [*grin*] ///// they ADDED that "grouping delay" in psv3 [or perhaps v4], so i am confident that they won't remove it. [*sigh ...*] it may not be in ps6, tho. i have not looked into that ...